# Getting VBA to apply a filter to a pivot table

Tags: vba, pivot-table

So as mentioned in the title I'm trying to apply a filter to a pivot table in my workbook as a part of a macro. I've tried dozens of different solutions from around the internet but to no avail.

This is what I've got so far, it successfully clears the old filters, so all I need is a line to assign filter "z" to the pivot field "IP5"

```
   Sub GetConsign()

    Dim y As Integer 
    Dim z As Integer 
    y = 4

    Worksheets("Master Data").Activate
    Cells(y, 7).Select
    z = Right(ActiveCell, 5)
    Worksheets("Cons Data").Activate

        Sheets("Cons Data").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IP5").ClearAllFilters

        'Need something to go here!

End Sub
```

I'd post an image of the table but apparently I need 10 reputation, nevermind.

Thanks, really appreciate any help I can get here, I'm bordering on insanity!

Comment: Is tagging VBA questions as VB.NET a (stupid) trend or what? VBA has nothing to do with VB.NET! Even the syntax is quite different (VBA is more similar to VB6, which is also completely different).

Comment: Apologies I'll edit the tags

Comment: No problem. Done already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sheets("Cons Data").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IP5").CurrentPage = "z"
```

or

```
Sheets("Cons Data").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IP5").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="z"
```

Comment: Gives me the error message: "Unable to set the currentpage property of the pivotfield class" Any idea what this means? Thanks though

Comment: oh, in that case you probably dont have it as a filter. Try this one

Sheets("Cons Data").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IP5").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="z", I put it in the original answer to make sure, because I it looks better with code format :-)

Comment: It Works! well except for that now it filters looking for the letter "z", whilst what I need it to filter is the variable z, which in the first case is 15217. Do I just need to change z to a different type of variable? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remove the quote signs around z. I got confused by your quotes in the descrption. Note to self: read the question better nex time

Comment: SUCCESS! thanks a lot man, you've just saved me about 4 hours work and a lot longer in future. Cheers:D